# Update Links of Powerpoint using win32com (Python)

Tags: python, powerpoint, win32com

I have a PowerPoint slide which has a linked image (table) and the data for that image is in excel.

I am trying to open the PowerPoint but even after `PPTApp.DisplayAlerts = False` my script gets stuck due to Security pop up which asks me to update the external links.

Here is my code:

```
import win32com.client
PPTApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")

if PPTApp.Visible == False:
    PPTApp.Visible = True
    
PPTApp.DisplayAlerts = False

#PPTApp.AskToUpdateLinks = False (this does not work)

PPTPresentation = PPTApp.Presentations.Open(r"C:\Daily_Data_Slide.pptx")
PPTPresentation.UpdateLinks = True
```

Comment: I don't know if this link is relevant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.application.automationsecurity

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.
       
secAutomation = excel.Application.AutomationSecurity

msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable = 3 

excel.Application.AutomationSecurity=msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable

Answer (score 0):

Just call UpdateLinks() instead of setting the attribute UpdateLinks to True, and remove the line where you are invoking alerts `PPTApp.DisplayAlerts = False` :

```
import win32com.client
PPTApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")

if not PPTApp.Visible:
   PPTApp.Visible = True

PPTPresentation = PPTApp.Presentations.Open(r"C:\Daily_Data_Slide.pptx")
PPTPresentation.UpdateLinks()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was able to work so far related to your question on my own projects.

I will first disable the Automatic Update for liks (File->Info->Edit Liks to file) to avoid getting stuck at the Security pop up which asks to update the external links. We will be update by looping through the slides and refreshing each shape if applicable.

Code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
from datetime import datetime
import time

path="\\\\Servername\\share$\\folder\\"
pptfile = "filename.pptx"
pptfilename=pptfile[:pptfile.find('.')] #filename without extension
date= datetime.now().strftime('%#d-%b-%Y')

pptApp = win32.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
pptApp.DisplayAlerts = 0
Presentation = pptApp.Presentations.Open(path+pptfile,0,0,0) # This hide the power point
# Then Search in all slides and if it is a Linked object (Type 10) then Refresh
for slide in Presentation.Slides:
    for shape in slide.Shapes:
        if shape.Type == 10:
            shape.LinkFormat.Update()
Presentation.SaveAs(FileName=path+pptfilename+"("+date+").pptx") # Save a copy with the date
Presentation.Close()
pptApp.Quit()
```